# Trying to choose between two paths on Rails view, depending on parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a HABTM relationship between `financing_campaign` and `financing_merchant`.

In one specific view, there can be a link_to to 2 possible paths. If there is a `@campaigns` variable, then the path should be:

(to display the merchant in the context of the campaign)

`financing_campaign_merchant_path(@campaign, merchant)` -
`/financing/campaigns/:id/merchants/:id`

else, it should be:

(to display the merchant without the context of the campaign)

`financing_merchant_path(merchant)` - 
`/financing/merchants/:id`

I'm trying to decide the best way to solve this. Currently we are using a ternary on the view, which seems ugly and confusing:

```
<% @merchants.each do |merchant| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to merchant.name, @campaign ? financing_campaign_merchant_path(@campaign, merchant) : financing_merchant_path(merchant) %>
   </td>
...
</%end>
```

routes.rb:

```
namespace :financing do
  resources :merchants
  resources :campaigns, only: %i[index show edit update] do
    resources :merchants, only: [:index, :show]
  ...
  end
end
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes best to keep it simple. I think what you have is solid, particularly if you are only going to use it in one place.

If you want to beautify the view code, though, you could elect to move the ugliness to a helper class, i.e:

```
module FinancingHelper

  def link_to_merchant(merchant, campaign=@campaign)
    link_to merchant.name, campaign ? financing_campaign_merchant_path(campaign, merchant) : financing_merchant_path(merchant)
  end

end
```

Then your view changes to:

```
<% @merchants.each do |merchant| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to_merchant merchant %>
   </td>
...
</%end>
```

If `@campaign` is defined in context, it will be found in the helper and use it; otherwise, it will link to just the merchant. Or, you could explicitly pass a `campaign` parameter to check, but this just means more code to type, and it seems like you like the "less is more" approach!